# Finding packages for TexLive

Tags: apt, software-installation, texlive

I installed TexStudio with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install texstudio
```

Now I need to install some packages like `amsmath` and `amsfonts`.
I typed in:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-<\t>
```

but I get hundred of proposals, I don't know which one to install to get the required packages.

How can I find out which `texlive-...`-component to install via `apt-get` to get the required packages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Ubuntu Software Center if you search for the name of the LaTeX package that you want (e.g. `amsmath`) you will find what you need ([e.g.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvcr9.jpg)).

Via command line you can do the same thing with `apt-cache`:

```
apt-cache search amsmath
texlive-latex-base - TeX Live: LaTeX fundamental packages
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages
texlive-math-extra - TeX Live: Mathematics packages
texlive-lang-italian - TeX Live: Italian
```

and then to be sure

```
apt-cache show texlive-latex-base
Package: texlive-latex-base

[...]

  amscls -- AMS document classes for LaTeX.
  amsmath -- AMS mathematical facilities for LaTeX.
  babel -- Multilingual support for Plain TeX or LaTeX.
```